# Virtual Box keeps crashing with message virtual box has stopped working

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtualization

I have Virtual Box 4.2.12 and while doing guest installation (Oracle Linux), virtual box keeps crashing with these message

**oracle vm virtual box has stopped working**

Application event log has the following logs

```
Faulting application name: VirtualBox.exe, version: 4.2.12.0, time stamp: 0x5167d6dc
Faulting module name: MSVCR100.dll, version: 10.0.40219.1, time stamp: 0x4d5f034a
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000000000003c145
Faulting process id: 0x810
Faulting application start time: 0x01ce47ed707ebd66
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\MSVCR100.dll
```

What could be the reason for this?

How can I resolve this?

Comment: I would try reinstalling `Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package`

Comment: @Ramhound I have noticed that after I finish installation and when I would want to login for the first time, if I switch to scale mode I am able to login to guest OS without any problem.

Comment: @Ramhound How can I install `Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package`?

Comment: Download it then install it?